# Pass const data to function taking non-const without const_cast

Tags: c++, constants

If I use `const_cast`, `Method(Xp_T* pParameters)` accepts a `const Xp_T&`
parameter type but I wouldn't prefer to use `const_cast` here and would like
to modify `Method(Xp_T* pParameters)` so, that it accepts a `const Xp_T&` parameter type.

```
bool Class::Method(const Parameters& rParameters )
{
    rParameters.Method(&m_Xp); // I wouldn't prefer to use const_cast here
    return true;
}
```

Base class Method:

```
template<typename Xp_T>
void Method(Xp_T* pParameters )
{
     (*pParameters) = (static_cast< Xp_T&>(*this));
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use `const_cast`?  It is designed to do exactly what you are doing, passing a `const*` to a legacy function that takes a `*` but will not modify it.

Comment: @NathanOliver it does modify it

Comment: That is really violating the contract. The first function says that it will not modify the value of the argument, then you go on and modify the value. Modifying constant data is also *undefined behavior*. ***Don't do it!***

Comment: @Slava Well that is also okay as long as the you know it the reference referes to a non `const` object.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour on attempting to modify a variable that was originally declared as `const` is *undefined*.

The only truly safe way is to take a value copy of the `const` variable, and pass that - or a pointer to that - into your non-`const` function. Any modifications made by the function will be discarded at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

If "Method" only is supposed to modify one or a few member variables inside "Class", one alternative is to declare those members **mutable** and then define a "Method2" that is declared const, but it will still be able to modify the mutables.